# How write about personal achievements? (tense choice)

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, idiomatic-language

Let's say I have  to describe my personal achievements during my work in some project. What tense should I use - the simple past or the present perfect?

The past simple

> Achievements:
>
> - Developed a whole software component
> - Proposed a new way to solve some problem
> - etc

or the present perfect

> Achievements:
>
> - Have developed a whole software component
> - Have proposed a new way to solve some problem
> - etc

Comment: Both are used.  Which is "better" is entirely personal opinion.

Comment: Thank you! Is it OK to use the present perfect to describe old achievements (e.g. if I was involved in project's development years ago and since then I haven't participated in it)?

Comment: "Right" or "wrong" are not really the issue.  The question is whether it *sounds* good in the overall context of your work history.  If you use it consistently, it might sound nice.  Used poorly, it can sound awkward.

Comment: Thank you again. By "consistently" do you mean "grammatical correctness" or "prefer it over the simple past in appropriate situations"? Or something else?

Comment: A resume is a *list* of accomplishments.  All of the elements of any list should be formatted in the same way:  I **built** this; I **designed** that, I **wrote** something else.  If you choose to use the present perfect, use it in a consistent way.  Don't just drop it in for one or two accomplishments.  That would look weird.  On the other hand, if you repeat **"have built"**, **"have designed"** etc. that's a lot of repeating "have" and "has" which can also look weird.  In any language, good writing style takes practice.

Comment: Present perfect looks strange to me in this context.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung What do you think is wrong with the present perfect in this context?

Comment: @embedc It strikes me as unnecessary, repetitive, insistent, overwrought... other than that, it's just not what people do in general—so it indicates ESL.

Answer (score 1):

Both are used. Which is "better" is entirely personal opinion.

A resume *is* a list of accomplishments. All of the elements of any list should be formatted in the same way:

> I built this;
>   I designed that,
>   I wrote something else.

If you choose to use the present perfect, use it in a consistent way. Don't just drop it in for one or two accomplishments. That would look weird. On the other hand, if you repeat "have built", "have designed" etc. that's a lot of repeating "have" and "has" which can also look weird.

In any language, good writing style takes practice.